# Setting Location Telegram Bot

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

I'm trying to recreate the same Telegram bot I previously created in Python, this time using Node.js. I've examined most of the Node.js modules and found only the "gramjs-sqlitesession" module for starting the bot with an SQLite session file, just like in Python. I believe I can use this module only in conjunction with the "telegram" module.

I can successfully start the bot in the code below, but I want to be able to set the bot's position based on a specific location and have it automatically respond when people send messages to the bot. However, I couldn't find any sample code for setting the bot's position in the "telegram" module. It seems like there are sample codes for setting the position in the "node-telegram-bot-api" module, but I can't use an SQLite session file with that module. How can I set the bot based on a specific coordinate?

```
const {TelegramClient} = require('telegram');
const SQLiteSession = require('gramjs-sqlitesession');


const API_ID = 123456789;
const API_HASH = '0bffff0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f';
const pathToSessionFile = "./telegram/{PHONENUMBER}.session";
const sqliteSession = new SQLiteSession(pathToSessionFile);

const client = new TelegramClient(sqliteSession, API_ID, API_HASH, {
  connectionRetries: 5,
});

async function startBot() {
  await client.start({
      onError: (err) => console.error(err),
  });
}

startBot().then(() => {
  console.log('Bot started');
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error starting the bot:', error);
});
```